# Django querysets. Annotate different fields with one query

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I wrote 3 queries to the database to get different values. I need to combine those queries to one query.

```
    # Counting Total Number of Plans by Day
    Day.objects.annotate(num_of_plans=Count('plan')) \
        .values('num_of_plans', 'date', 'id')

    # Counting is_completed=True Plans by Day
             Day.objects \
            .filter(plan__is_completed=True) \
            .annotate(num_of_completed_plans=Count('plan__is_completed')) \
            .values('num_of_completed_plans', 'id', 'date')


     # Counting status=deferred Plans by Day
       Day.objects \
            .filter(plan__status='deferred') \
            .annotate(num_of_deferred_plans=Count('plan__is_completed')) \
            .values('num_of_deferred_plans', 'id', 'date')
```

As you can see above there 3 queries. Somehow I need to optimize this code and get values with the help of one query

**models**

```
class Day(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today, unique=True)

class Plan(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=PLAN_STATUSES, null=True, default='upcoming')
    is_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True)

    day = models.ForeignKey(Day, CASCADE, null=True)
```

Are there any ways to optimize that 3 queries and get values with one query?

Comment: What Django version do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [django-2.0](/questions/tagged/django-2.0), you can use the [**`filter=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate-filter) in the `Count` expression. As for the filtering on a `Bool`, you can just use a [**`Sum`** expression [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#sum):

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q, Sum

Day.objects.annotate(
    num_of_plans=Count('plan'),
    num_of_completed_plans=Sum('plan__is_completed'),
    num_of_deferred_plans=Count('plan', filter=Q(plan__status='deferred'))
)
```

Normally it is better *not* to use `.values()`. But make use of the objects (that have extra attributes), since then you keep the logic you define on your model intact.